# Pandas DataFrame: set_index with inplace=True returns a NoneType, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I reset the index of my pandas DataFrame with  "inplace=True" (following [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)) it returns a class 'NoneType'. If I reset the index with "inplace=False" it returns the DataFrame with the new index. Why?

```
print(type(testDataframe))
print(testDataframe.head())
```

returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    ALandbouwBosbouwEnVisserij AantalInkomensontvangers  AantalInwoners  \
0                     73780.0                     None        16979120   
1                       290.0                     None           25243   
2                        20.0                     None            3555
```

Set_index returns a new index:

```
testDataframe = testDataframe.set_index(['Codering'])
    print(type(testDataframe))
    print(testDataframe.head())
```

returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
            ALandbouwBosbouwEnVisserij AantalInkomensontvangers  \
Codering                                                          
NL00                           73780.0                     None   
GM1680                           290.0                     None   
WK168000                          20.0                     None   
BU16800000                        15.0                     None
```

But the same set_index with "inplace=True":

```
testDataframe = testDataframe.set_index(['Codering'], inplace=True)
print(type(testDataframe))
print(testDataframe.head())
```

returns

```
<class 'NoneType'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-0d6304ebaae1> in <module>()
```

Version info:

```
python: 3.4.4.final.0
python-bits: 64
pandas: 0.18.1
numpy: 1.11.1
IPython: 5.2.2
```

Comment: Because it's inplace so the object is modified, why should it return the new modified object? If you passed `inplace=False` then it returns the new modified object, did you check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)? It's pretty clear: `inplace : boolean, default False. Modify the DataFrame in place (do not create a new object)`

Comment: Why should it return something? It does the modification **inplace**, meaning the current dataframe is updated.

Comment: It is interesting to return the object itself, so you can do things like `df = df.<do something not inplace>().reset_index(inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok, now I understand, thanks for the comments!

So inplace=True should return None **and** make the change in the original object. It seemed that on listing the dataframe again, no changes were present.

But of course I should not have **assigned the return value** to the dataframe, i.e.

```
testDataframe = testDataframe.set_index(['Codering'], inplace=True)
```

should just be

```
testDataframe.set_index(['Codering'], inplace=True)
```

or

```
testDataframe = testDataframe.set_index(['Codering'], inplace=False)
```

otherwise the return value of the inplace index change (None) is the new content of the dataframe which is of course not the intend.

I am sure this is obvious to many and now it is to me as well but it wasn't without your help, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

inplace=True is always changed in the original data_frame. If you want a changed data_frame then remove second parameter i.e `inplace = True`

```
new_data_frame = testDataframe.set_index(['Codering'])
```

Then

```
print(new_data_frame)
```