# Python Pandas Commands .replace() Not Working despite inplace = True

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use `.replace()` on a DataFrame made from `.read_excel()`. The command is not working despite using inplace = True, and triple-checking the spelling (copy pasted from original excel doc)

```
import pandas as pd

def create_frame(path):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
    return df1.replace(('Visit 2: Day 1','Day 1'), inplace = True)

df = create_frame('example.xlsx')
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

i've also tried using `df2 = df1.replace(('Visit 2: Day 1','Day 1'))` instead of using `inplace = True` but the test csv always comes out with 'Visit 2: Day 1'

I'm having a similar dysfunction (commands not working) with `.sort_values` and `.reset_index` as well.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong? All help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: If you using `inplace = True` in `replace` then it will return `None`, and  your `to_replace` argument seems have wrong format, what exactly you want replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the function `create_frame` without `inplace=True`.

if you use `inplace=True`, it will return `None` from the func `create_frame`.

similarly, [Pandas dataframe: set_index with inplace=True returns a NoneType, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854598/pandas-dataframe-set-index-with-inplace-true-returns-a-nonetype-why)?

```
import pandas as pd

def create_frame(path):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
    return df1.replace(('Visit 2: Day 1','Day 1'))

df = create_frame('example.xlsx')
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

---

when you use `df2 = df1.replace(('Visit 2: Day 1','Day 1'))`, it will not affect `df1`.

so without use func, you can do like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
df2 = df1.replace(('Visit 2: Day 1','Day 1'))
df2.to_csv('test.csv')

df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
df1.replace(('Visit 2: Day 1','Day 1'), inplace=True)
df1.to_csv('test.csv')
```