# Transforming a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data as below:

| Unnamed :5 | Week 5 | Week4 | Week3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Quartiles | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| CR | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| KPI | 4 | 5 | 2 |
| Quartiles | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| CR | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| KPI | 3 | 4 | 1 |

I need to transform the file as below:

| Week | Quartiles | CR | KPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week5 | 2 | 1 | 4 |
| Week4 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| Week3 | 4 | 5 | 2 |
| Week5 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| Week4 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| Week3 | 4 | 3 | 1 |

Which function can I use in pandas: `unstack()`, `pivot()`, `crosstab()`?
I'm confused on which is right methodology to use..

Please help me to overcome this.

Thanks

As I new to pandas I tried to use `unstack()` and `reset_index()` which is not working.
Also I have tried with `pivot_table()`.
Not sure which is right way to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to Transpose the dataframe. Make sure to set the unnamed column to the index and then transpose the dataframe as:

```
#set the index
df1.set_index("Unnamed :5", inplace=True)

#transpose to the dataframe
df1_transposed = df1.T
```

To then change the week from the index you can use:

```
df1_transposed.reset_index(inplace=True)

df1_transposed.rename(columns = {"index":"Week"},
     inplace = true)
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html for more details.

Comment: thanks @philip09m  When I trying to set index it is changing to nontype object.. what can I do?

Comment: @Krishnamoorthy potentially put "Unnamed :5" in [] so .set_index(["Unnamed :5"], inplace=True)

Comment: It should also be expected to return a Nonetype as it will change the original dataframe. So if you carry out the remaining commands it should still work. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854598/pandas-dataframe-set-index-with-inplace-true-returns-a-nonetype-why @Krishnamoorthy

Comment: it is converting to many columns and few rows(week5,week4,week3), but I need output as only 3 columns(quartiles,CR,KPI) with many records or rows...how to do that?

Comment: Hmmm, that makes it a bit of a challenge. You could potentially melt and then pivot. so

```
melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ["Unnamed: 5"], value_vars = ["week5", "week4", "week3"])
pivot = melted.pivot(index="variable", columns = "Unnamed: 5", values = "value")
```

@Krishnamoorthy

Comment: thanks philip, Melt worked, but pivoting throws an error stating "index contains duplicate entries cannot reshape".. how to avoid duplicates here.

Comment: I'm not sure sorry! I would probably advise retitling your question title to attract other help because its no't that description at the moment

Comment: Will try to ask another question or title. thanks for your suggestion!!!

Comment: No worries. Apologies I wasn't able to help anymore!